# IOS: How to have different fonts per scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have an app that needs to be customized according to several customer. I would like to add a different font/scheme. How to achieve this? I would like to keep the same xib for all scheme and font name is defined in the xib.

Comment: You can do it by code, but I'm not sure you can do it by only xibs/storyboards.

Comment: Even by code would be fine if it needs to be done only once for all font reference.....

Comment: Can someone post the code for this? Thanks a lot!